# how to get java bufferReader performace in c++ when parsing csv file which contain string values

Tags: c++, csv, io

I have a data file with values separated by `|` such as:

```
1|true|f|5|11209
2|false|g|6|90945
```

the file is quite large (~112MB). With Java I managed to use BufferedReader and FileReader and managed to parse this file in less than a second. I am trying to achieve the same performance on c++, but I know that my code is not optimised for speed because of a nested for loop like this:

```
ifstream infile(filename);
string line;
while(getline(infile, line))
{
    string item;
    stringstream ss(line);
    vector<string> splittedString;
    while(getline(ss, item, '|'))
    {
        splittedString.push_back(item);
    }
    // do some work with the current row and continue
}
```

I am not storing the whole file in memory first but going with this line by line approach for other reasons but the java code is exactly the same so it is not the issue at hand.

How can this kind of parsing be optimized in c++? since I am more versed in java I/O

Comment: You _did_ run this in release mode, right?

Comment: @Botje the java to  c++ is more experimental than final release if that's what you mean. But you can clearly see why the c++ is slower from the above code right?

Comment: Just making sure that you are compiling with *optimizations turned on*. There is simply no point in talking about speed before you do that.

Comment: how do you turn optimization on? I don't follow

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Visual Studio? Xcode? Code::Blocks? raw `g++` calls? Search Google for that plus "enable optimizations"

Comment: In this small piece of code . . .  You know that your vector has always 5 elements. You define an empty vector for every line and the push back values 5 times. You read a string from an fstream, put that into a stringstream and read again from the stringstream to split up.   In my opinion, there is a lot of optimization potential in the algorithm . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny I know there is a lot of optimization potential. That is the whole point of why I posted the question... for some help on optimization. If you have any ideas about this I appreciate an answer instead of a comment that justifies the question. Thanks.